# Obtener Saldo anterior de una cuenta en base al saldo actual - SQL

Tags: sql, tsql, transact-sql

Tengo esta tabla

```
SELECT 
Fecha, DescripcionTransaccion Retiro, Deposito, SaldoActual, Cuenta 
FROM Tabla
WHERE Cuenta = '0254789'
```

la cual me arroja toda la transaccionalidad de esa cuenta desde la apertura de la misma hasta la fecha donde se consulte, el campo SaldoActual es el saldo al dia

Comparto resultado de ejemplo:

```
Fecha     DescripcionTransaccion    Retiro    Deposito SaldoActual   Cuenta  
1/10/2023   CAPITALIZACION              0      18.06      21146      254789
1/10/2023   DEPOSITO                    0      1000       21146      254789
1/10/2023   TRANSFERENCIA               0      108825.05  21146      254789
1/10/2023   TRANSFERENCIA               0      3000       21146      254789
1/10/2023   TRANSFERENCIA               35     0          21146      254789
1/10/2023   TRANSFERENCIA            152000    0          21146      254789
1/10/2023   UTILITY                  142.5     0          21146      254789
1/10/2023   TRANSFERENCIA              0       3000       21146      254789
1/10/2023   DEPOSITO                   0       1000       21146      254789
1/10/2023   TRANSFERENCIA             35       0          21146      254789
2/10/2023   TRANSFERENCIA             500      0          21146      254789
2/10/2023   DEPOSITO                  0        1000       21146      254789
2/10/2023   DEPOSITO                  0        10000      21146      254789
2/10/2023   DEPOSITO                  0        1000       21146      254789
2/10/2023   DEPOSITO                  0        1000       21146      254789
2/10/2023   DEPOSITO                  0        1000       21146      254789
2/10/2023   DEPOSITO                  0        1000       21146      254789
3/10/2023   TRANSFERENCIA             35       0          21146      254789
3/10/2023   TRANSFERENCIA            1000      0          21146      254789
3/10/2023   RETIRO                   3000      0          21146      254789
3/10/2023   RETIRO                   24        0          21146      254789
3/10/2023   RETIRO                    5000     0          21146      254789
3/10/2023   RETIRO                    24       0          21146      254789
3/10/2023   TRANSFERENCIA             0        1365       21146      254789
3/10/2023   DEPOSITO                  0        1000       21146      254789
4/10/2023   DEPOSITO                  0        5000       21146      254789
4/10/2023   CAPITALIZACION            0        66.2       21146      254789
4/10/2023   DEPOSITO                  0        1000       21146      254789
4/10/2023   DEPOSITO                  0        1000       21146      254789
4/10/2023   DEPOSITO                  0        750        21146      254789
5/10/2023   DEPOSITO                  0        1000       21146      254789
5/10/2023   DEPOSITO                  0        1000       21146      254789
5/10/2023   TRANSFERENCIA             0        6000       21146      254789
6/10/2023   COMPRA                    3542.85   0         21146      254789
6/10/2023   DEPOSITO                  0        6000       21146      254789
6/10/2023   TRANSFERENCIA             0        1700       21146      254789
6/10/2023   TRANSFERENCIA             35        0         21146      254789
```

Entonces lo que quiero hacer es algo similar a un Estado de Cuenta, por ejemplo si yo saco el estado de Cuenta de esa cuenta en las fechas del 01/10/2023 al 06/10/2023, el saldo inicial con el que se va a comenzar a restar y sumar los débitos sea calculado en base al SaldoActual (ósea tomar el SaldoActual e ir para atrás) hasta llegar al saldo que tenia antes de la fecha de inicio (01/10/2023)

Por ejemplo, según la consulta dada si mi SaldoActual es de 21,146 y coloque como FechaInicio 01/10/2023 debo de ir Restando si es retiro y sumando si es deposito ese saldo para atras, para llegar al valor a un dia antes de la Fecha inicio colocada que en este caso el valor seria 13,496.96‬, y a partir de ese valor ir realizando normalmente el Estado de Cuenta

Resultado Esperado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

asi hasta llegar a la fecha Final

Entiendo que se puede hacer mediante una funcion de ventana, sin embargo no se como hacer para en base al saldo anctual ir para atras, si alguien me ayuda porfa

Comment: En primer lugar, deberías usar el sistema de doble apunte contable con el debe y el haber: el dinero ni se crea ni se destruye, cambia de cuenta. Si insistes en hacerlo como planteas, a pesar de las complicaciones a largo plazo, ayúdanos a ayudarte pasándonos un dataset en SQL con datos de ejemplo para entender de dónde partes, a dónde quieres llegar y, sobre todo, categoriza las transacciones entre ingreso o gasto para saber si suman o restan al saldo. Puedes crear una tabla transacciones en las que lo detalles, por ejemplo

Comment: por qué el saldo actual es constante en toda la cartola, mientras que el saldo inicial va cambiando? Los subtotales obtenidos mediante window functions debieran ser consistentes entre sí

Comment: @ffflabs La columna SaldoInicial debería llamarse simplemente saldo. El saldo inicial aparece justo a la derecha del texto SaldoInicial. Son cosas de las hojas de cálculo, que permiten esas licencias... Por otra parte, ten en cuenta que ese saldo inicial está mal calculado :)

Comment: Agradezco la aclaración, pero me sigue pareciendo que los datos de arriba no tienen pies ni cabeza

Answer (score 0):

En primer lugar, deberías usar el sistema de doble apunte contable con el debe y el haber: el dinero ni se crea ni se destruye, cambia de cuenta.

Si insistes en hacerlo como planteas, a pesar de las complicaciones a largo plazo que te traerá, el primer paso sería dotar a la tabla de un campo autonumérico que fije el orden de los registros y otro en el que llevar el saldo y así te permita prescindir del campo SaldoActual, que repites en cada registro y tampoco aporta demasiado:

```
ALTER TABLE Tabla
  ADD Id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  ADD Saldo decimal(10,2);
```

Después, ejecutando esta consulta, actualizarás el saldo tras cada movimiento:

```
SET @saldo:=(
    SELECT SaldoActual+SUM(Retiro)-SUM(Deposito) FROM Tabla
  );
UPDATE Tabla JOIN (
    SELECT Id,@saldo:=@saldo+Deposito-Retiro SaldoId
      FROM Tabla  
      ORDER BY Id
  ) c1 USING(Id)
  SET Saldo=SaldoId;
```

Obteniendo el resultado:

```
+------------+------------------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+--------+----+-----------+
| Fecha      | DescripcionTransaccion | Retiro    | Deposito  | SaldoActual | Cuenta | Id | Saldo     |
+------------+------------------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+--------+----+-----------+
| 2023-10-01 | CAPITALIZACION         |      0.00 |     18.06 |    21146.00 | 254789 |  1 |  28813.10 |
| 2023-10-01 | DEPOSITO               |      0.00 |   1000.00 |    21146.00 | 254789 |  2 |  29813.10 |
| 2023-10-01 | TRANSFERENCIA          |      0.00 | 108825.05 |    21146.00 | 254789 |  3 | 138638.15 |
| 2023-10-01 | TRANSFERENCIA          |      0.00 |   3000.00 |    21146.00 | 254789 |  4 | 141638.15 |
| 2023-10-01 | TRANSFERENCIA          |     35.00 |      0.00 |    21146.00 | 254789 |  5 | 141603.15 |
| 2023-10-01 | TRANSFERENCIA          | 152000.00 |      0.00 |    21146.00 | 254789 |  6 | -10396.85 |
| 2023-10-01 | UTILITY                |    142.50 |      0.00 |    21146.00 | 254789 |  7 | -10539.35 |
| 2023-10-01 | TRANSFERENCIA          |      0.00 |   3000.00 |    21146.00 | 254789 |  8 |  -7539.35 |
| 2023-10-01 | DEPOSITO               |      0.00 |   1000.00 |    21146.00 | 254789 |  9 |  -6539.35 |
| 2023-10-01 | TRANSFERENCIA          |     35.00 |      0.00 |    21146.00 | 254789 | 10 |  -6574.35 |
| 2023-10-02 | TRANSFERENCIA          |    500.00 |      0.00 |    21146.00 | 254789 | 11 |  -7074.35 |
| 2023-10-02 | DEPOSITO               |      0.00 |   1000.00 |    21146.00 | 254789 | 12 |  -6074.35 |
| 2023-10-02 | DEPOSITO               |      0.00 |  10000.00 |    21146.00 | 254789 | 13 |   3925.65 |
| 2023-10-02 | DEPOSITO               |      0.00 |   1000.00 |    21146.00 | 254789 | 14 |   4925.65 |
| 2023-10-02 | DEPOSITO               |      0.00 |   1000.00 |    21146.00 | 254789 | 15 |   5925.65 |
| 2023-10-02 | DEPOSITO               |      0.00 |   1000.00 |    21146.00 | 254789 | 16 |   6925.65 |
| 2023-10-02 | DEPOSITO               |      0.00 |   1000.00 |    21146.00 | 254789 | 17 |   7925.65 |
| 2023-10-03 | TRANSFERENCIA          |     35.00 |      0.00 |    21146.00 | 254789 | 18 |   7890.65 |
| 2023-10-03 | TRANSFERENCIA          |   1000.00 |      0.00 |    21146.00 | 254789 | 19 |   6890.65 |
| 2023-10-03 | RETIRO                 |   3000.00 |      0.00 |    21146.00 | 254789 | 20 |   3890.65 |
| 2023-10-03 | RETIRO                 |     24.00 |      0.00 |    21146.00 | 254789 | 21 |   3866.65 |
| 2023-10-03 | RETIRO                 |   5000.00 |      0.00 |    21146.00 | 254789 | 22 |  -1133.35 |
| 2023-10-03 | RETIRO                 |     24.00 |      0.00 |    21146.00 | 254789 | 23 |  -1157.35 |
| 2023-10-03 | TRANSFERENCIA          |      0.00 |   1365.00 |    21146.00 | 254789 | 24 |    207.65 |
| 2023-10-03 | DEPOSITO               |      0.00 |   1000.00 |    21146.00 | 254789 | 25 |   1207.65 |
| 2023-10-04 | DEPOSITO               |      0.00 |   5000.00 |    21146.00 | 254789 | 26 |   6207.65 |
| 2023-10-04 | CAPITALIZACION         |      0.00 |     66.20 |    21146.00 | 254789 | 27 |   6273.85 |
| 2023-10-04 | DEPOSITO               |      0.00 |   1000.00 |    21146.00 | 254789 | 28 |   7273.85 |
| 2023-10-04 | DEPOSITO               |      0.00 |   1000.00 |    21146.00 | 254789 | 29 |   8273.85 |
| 2023-10-04 | DEPOSITO               |      0.00 |    750.00 |    21146.00 | 254789 | 30 |   9023.85 |
| 2023-10-05 | DEPOSITO               |      0.00 |   1000.00 |    21146.00 | 254789 | 31 |  10023.85 |
| 2023-10-05 | DEPOSITO               |      0.00 |   1000.00 |    21146.00 | 254789 | 32 |  11023.85 |
| 2023-10-05 | TRANSFERENCIA          |      0.00 |   6000.00 |    21146.00 | 254789 | 33 |  17023.85 |
| 2023-10-06 | COMPRA                 |   3542.85 |      0.00 |    21146.00 | 254789 | 34 |  13481.00 |
| 2023-10-06 | DEPOSITO               |      0.00 |   6000.00 |    21146.00 | 254789 | 35 |  19481.00 |
| 2023-10-06 | TRANSFERENCIA          |      0.00 |   1700.00 |    21146.00 | 254789 | 36 |  21181.00 |
| 2023-10-06 | TRANSFERENCIA          |     35.00 |      0.00 |    21146.00 | 254789 | 37 |  21146.00 |
+------------+------------------------+-----------+-----------+-------------+--------+----+-----------+
```

Que no se parece a tu captura de pantalla porque tienes algunos errores, entre ellos un 15200 en vez de el 152000 que aparece en tu dataset.

Aporto tu dataset en SQL por si quieres realizar comprobaciones:

```
CREATE TABLE Tabla(
  Fecha date,
  DescripcionTransaccion varchar(31),
  Retiro decimal(10,2),
  Deposito decimal(10,2),
  SaldoActual decimal(10,2),
  Cuenta int
  );
INSERT INTO Tabla VALUES
('2023-10-1','CAPITALIZACION','0','18.06',21146.0,'254789'),
('2023-10-1','DEPOSITO','0','1000',21146.0,'254789'),
('2023-10-1','TRANSFERENCIA','0','108825.05',21146.0,'254789'),
('2023-10-1','TRANSFERENCIA','0','3000',21146.0,'254789'),
('2023-10-1','TRANSFERENCIA','35','0',21146.0,'254789'),
('2023-10-1','TRANSFERENCIA','152000','0',21146.0,'254789'),
('2023-10-1','UTILITY','142.5','0',21146.0,'254789'),
('2023-10-1','TRANSFERENCIA','0','3000',21146.0,'254789'),
('2023-10-1','DEPOSITO','0','1000',21146.0,'254789'),
('2023-10-1','TRANSFERENCIA','35','0',21146.0,'254789'),
('2023-10-2','TRANSFERENCIA','500','0',21146.0,'254789'),
('2023-10-2','DEPOSITO','0','1000',21146.0,'254789'),
('2023-10-2','DEPOSITO','0','10000',21146.0,'254789'),
('2023-10-2','DEPOSITO','0','1000',21146.0,'254789'),
('2023-10-2','DEPOSITO','0','1000',21146.0,'254789'),
('2023-10-2','DEPOSITO','0','1000',21146.0,'254789'),
('2023-10-2','DEPOSITO','0','1000',21146.0,'254789'),
('2023-10-3','TRANSFERENCIA','35','0',21146.0,'254789'),
('2023-10-3','TRANSFERENCIA','1000','0',21146.0,'254789'),
('2023-10-3','RETIRO','3000','0',21146.0,'254789'),
('2023-10-3','RETIRO','24','0',21146.0,'254789'),
('2023-10-3','RETIRO','5000','0',21146.0,'254789'),
('2023-10-3','RETIRO','24','0',21146.0,'254789'),
('2023-10-3','TRANSFERENCIA','0','1365',21146.0,'254789'),
('2023-10-3','DEPOSITO','0','1000',21146.0,'254789'),
('2023-10-4','DEPOSITO','0','5000',21146.0,'254789'),
('2023-10-4','CAPITALIZACION','0','66.2',21146.0,'254789'),
('2023-10-4','DEPOSITO','0','1000',21146.0,'254789'),
('2023-10-4','DEPOSITO','0','1000',21146.0,'254789'),
('2023-10-4','DEPOSITO','0','750',21146.0,'254789'),
('2023-10-5','DEPOSITO','0','1000',21146.0,'254789'),
('2023-10-5','DEPOSITO','0','1000',21146.0,'254789'),
('2023-10-5','TRANSFERENCIA','0','6000',21146.0,'254789'),
('2023-10-6','COMPRA','3542.85','0',21146.0,'254789'),
('2023-10-6','DEPOSITO','0','6000',21146.0,'254789'),
('2023-10-6','TRANSFERENCIA','0','1700',21146.0,'254789'),
('2023-10-6','TRANSFERENCIA','35','0',21146.0,'254789');
```

Comment: Hola, he intentado realizar tu respuesta sin embargo no logro comprender tu logia, la variable porque le colocas ":" , ese UPDATE debo de meterlo dentro de un Ciclo o como? lamento la ignorancia

Comment: En la documentación de MySQL tienes toda la información sobre el uso de variables: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html No es necesario ningún bucle, cada registro de la query hace la función de una iteración que actualiza el valor de la variable

Comment: Sólo tienes que ejecutar las queries tal y como te las he dado, no hace falta que definas ningún bucle

Comment: Yo no estoy usando MySQL, estoy utilizando T-SQL con SQL Management Studio, y me arroja error por eso

Comment: Ah, perdona... Pues ni idea de cómo se hará en SQL Server, será cuestión de investigarlo un poco